# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property of object '[object Object]' angular

Tags: angular, typeerror

I am trying to assign a value to a class property but getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'searchVal' of object '[object Object]'

The first assignment of this property works but then on the second clickEvent I get the error.

Not sure what the cause is?

```
export interface MyObject{
  searchVal: string
}

export class MyComponent{
  filter: MyObject = {
   searchVal: ''
  }

  search(val: string){
    this.filter.searchVal = val;
  }
}
```

```
<input
  type="text"
  (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"
  (keyup.enter)="search($event.target.value)"/>
```

Edit:

Fixed with this

```
this.filter = {...this.filter, searchVal: val};
```

Comment: It works in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gju7tg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: this is always the same value. Although when I do change it, it works. Could this be a config issue with angular then?

Comment: the code above is no problem. Can you share code to stackblitz?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like a code issue after all. Is there something in angular/typescript config that could be causing this?

Comment: _"Is there something in angular/typescript config that could be causing this?"_ - This is too generic of a question. You would have to show more information. How does the rest of the component look? Is the `this.filter` accessed/set elsewhere? How does the template look?

Comment: agree with Michael, there are many reasons for this problem. I think angular/typescript config is not the cause of the problem above

Comment: Template added.